# Is there a way to add "Collation" in to Django 1.3 query?

Tags: django, collation

I need to make a get query like:

```
obj = Current.objects.get(Code='M01.C0001')
```

But the query giving "Multiple Objects Returned' error because of the database has another record with similar unicode string 'M01.**Ç**0001'

```
[<obj: M01.Ç0001>, <obj: M01.C0001>]
```

I try to fetch data with field lookup functions, but it does not work anyway.

I googled around but I didn't find a way to temporarily set the Collation for this query.

Is it possible to temporarily set collation during executing a get query in Django 1.3?

**SOLUTION:**
I solved my problem with using raw django query with adding `COLLATE` to sql string.

```
obj = Current.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM Current WHERE Code = 'M01.C0001' COLLATE utf8_bin;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Collation is a database property, so you cannot do that.
Change collation to database.