# Django - Q Object - 'i__contains' to include accents?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i have the following line of code:

```
list = Database.objets.filter(Q(name__icontains=searchstring))
```

So for example if:

```
searchstring = Georges Méliès
```

It returns the result, but if:

```
searchstring = Georges Melies
```

It doesn't get it.

Is there any way i can "tell" Django to ignore accents on letters? Such as here in the case of `e`? (i'm using `PostgreSQL`)

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that starting `Django 1.8`, you can utilize its ORM's "unaccent" database lookup for `Postgres`.

Is this the solution?

Comment: Search for "collation".

Comment: It appears to be limited support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637967/is-there-a-way-to-add-collation-in-to-django-1-3-query (indepth explanation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-updates/AZaCDhba1YM) You'll probably also want to tag the db version/adapter used.

Comment: It's PostgreSQL.